# Asana Task Logs - How to get it?

Tags: api, logging, asana

Asana lack of reporting is bugging my team, so we are trying to use the asana's API to generate at least basic reporting.

Is it possible to get the task logs that are shown in the task details?

In the task details I can see this:
`User created task.Mar 25
 User added to proj1.Mar 25
 User moved from proj1 to label2 (proj1).Mar 25
 User assigned to UserX.9:22am`

How can I get it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the [documentation](http://developer.asana.com/documentation/#stories.query) you can get what we call the "stories" for an object using `GET /tasks/:id/stories`. Note that the creation task we display in the app is actually displayed from the task data, and not a story in its own right: you can determine this by looking at the value of `created_at` for the task itself using `GET /tasks/:id?opt_fields=created_at`, for instance.